# How can I record 8-bit audio with PyAudio?

Tags: python, pyaudio

PyAudio works with pyaudio.paInt16, but when I try to use pyaudio.paInt8 or pyaudio.paUInt8, I can only hear noise.

```
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
inStream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt8,
                  channels=1,
                  rate=8000,
                  input=True)

outStream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt8,
                   channels=1,
                   rate=8000,
                   output=True)

print(p.get_default_input_device_info())
while True:
    data = inStream.read(160)
    print(data)
    # outStream.write(data)
```

Here is my mic info:

```
{'index': 1, 'structVersion': 2, 'name': 'Headset Microphone (INZONE H9 /', 'hostApi': 0, 'maxInputChannels': 1, 'maxOutputChannels': 0, 'defaultLowInputLatency': 0.09, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.09, 'defaultHighInputLatency': 0.18, 'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.18, 'defaultSampleRate': 44100.0}
```

and the audio content:

```
b'\x14\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00p;\xfd\xcc\xd0\x01\x00\x00\xf0<\xfd\xcc\xd0\x01\x00\x00\xf0;\xfd\xcc\xd0\x01\x00\x00\xb06\xfd\xcc\xd0\x01\x00\x000\xb5\x1b\xcf\xd0\x01\x00\x00\x90\xe4\x1b\xcf\xd0\x01\x00\x000\x05\xfd\xcc\xd0\x01\x00\x00pq\xff\xcc\xd0\x01\x00\x00\xc0+\x1b\xcf\xd0\x01\x00\x00\x10,\x1b\xcf\xd0\x01\x00\x00p\xbc\x1b\xcf\xd0\x01\x00\x00\xb0\xbc\x1b\xcf\xd0\x01\x00\x000\xbb\x1b\xcf\xd0\x01\x00\x00\xf0\xbc\x1b\xcf\xd0\x01\x00\x000\xbd\x1b\xcf\xd0\x01\x00\x00p\xbd\x1b\xcf\xd0\x01\x00\x00pr\xff\xcc\xd0\x01\x00\x00\xb0\x1f\x05\xcd\xd0\x01\x00\x00\xa0\xe3\x1b\xcf\xd0\x01\x00\x00'
```

This audio content is the same even when the mic is off.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Are you sure 8 bits will be enough?  That's not a lot for audio.

Comment: `pyAudio` looks like it is a wrapper around `portAudio`.  You could try to dig through the documentation of both those projects to determine why this doesn't work.  Or you could generate some tests on your end to see what appears to work for you.  What happens sometimes on these wrappers is that only parts of the underlying are supported, or there is no one to work on the project to keep it up to date.  It is possible that 8 bit doesn't work, or doesn't work on your particular hardware.  Hard to say what is occurring without spending a fair amount of time really digging into the root cause.

Comment: What I would probably attempt to do in this case is generate a simple sine wave tone at a reasonable frequency (400 Hz?) and attempt to play it back at both the 16 bit and 8 bit modes and see what happens.

Comment: If the desire here is simply to play audio that sounds like 8-bit, you can still use the 16-bit playback to do that.  Take your input and clip it to 256 levels within the 16-bit space, that should give you an 8-bit effect, even if you can only get the 16-bit playback to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

*(This answer is rather late, posting for the benefit of future readers.)*

Your code is fine. The issue is caused by a bug in the PortAudio library; it triggers on certain systems that don't support paInt8 natively (details below).

Until this bug is fixed in PortAudio, I suggest you switch to a different format; for example, if your device supports paUInt8 (unsigned 8-bit, where [128 is "ground"](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs-dev/portaudio_8h.html#a4582d93c2c2e60e12be3d74c5fe00b96)), you can use that and manually convert the data to paInt8 (signed 8-bit):

```
import pyaudio
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
inStream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paUInt8, # <-- changed from paInt8
                  channels=1,
                  rate=8000,
                  input=True)

outStream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt8,
                   channels=1,
                   rate=8000,
                   output=True)

print(p.get_default_input_device_info())
while True:
    data = inStream.read(160)
    data = bytes([b ^ 0x80 for b in data]) # convert from paUInt8 to paInt8
    # print(data)
    outStream.write(data)
```

---

Details:

Some systems (e.g. the Linux VM I tested with) don't support paInt8 (signed 8-bit, aka S8). In my test, PortAudio tried to record as paInt16, then convert to paInt8 with [dithering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither#Digital_audio) to improve the quality; however [that code is not implemented](https://github.com/PortAudio/portaudio/blob/2fe67f3568295accc0b4cc47cefd5e0d6a7f6e43/src/common/pa_converters.c#L1414) so it produces garbage.

Comment: `/* IMPLEMENT ME */` nice.  Just fail silently instead of throwing an error.  This type of thing plus the wrapper on wrapper on wrapper telephone game can cause these types of things.  Cool to see someone dig into the root cause to know exactly how in this case.